# How to concatenate N' strings on insert in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert strings into a NVARCHAR as I was having problem with characters not going into the db properly.

e.g. I have strings I want to put into my db but to get the special characters to show up it seems I need the N' to store Unicode.

```
N'I used tö like SQL'
```

But sometimes these string already have single quote in them.
e.g.

```
"I dön't anymore"
```

How do I concatenate these strings so that the still store the Unicode. I thought something like this would work but I'm having no luck.

```
(N'' + "I dön't anymõre")
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Double the single quote in a literal, like `N'I dön''t anymõre'`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Is it possible that you think the type indicator is `N'`? It is just `N`. So if double quoting is also allowed in your RDBMS, what about `N"I dön't anymore"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include an apostrophe in an SQL string you need to double the apostrophe, as in:

```
N'I dön''t anymore'
```

String concatenation, on the other hand, performed with the `||` operator as in

```
N'This is the first substring' || N' and here''s the secönd substring'
```

will produce

```
This is the first substring and here's the secönd substring
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3595cb3c34a8acb9d5165182a0bd9dfd)

Comment: Not the concatenation operator is the question, but you showed properly that each string must have an `N`.

Comment: Well, since the title of the question says `How to concatenate...` and the user wasn't using the correct SQL concatenation operator I thought it would be a good idea to give an example.

Comment: Without the RDBMS there is no `correct concatenation operator` - try your example in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to store quotes you simply double them up:

```
declare @string nvarchar(50)
set @string=N'I dön''t anymõre'
print @string
```

Edit - You don't state a particlar platform however I'm assuming SQLServer, doubling single quotes works on most platforms.

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh . .. The answer is not product specific.  Doubling the single quote is the SQL standard way of inserting a single quote.  Of course, the `declare` and `print` are product specific, but those are secondary to the answer.